# React - Accessing inline created iframe elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have an iframe and I'm trying to access it's textarea and add a listener:

```
    onIframeRef = (node) => {
       this.Iframe = node;
    };

  componentDidMount() {
      let iframeDoc = this.Iframe.contentDocument || this.Iframe.contentWindow.document;
      let textArea = iframeDoc.contentWindow.document.getElementById("some-textarea")[0];
      textArea.addEventListener("input", this.onInput);
   }

    render() {
            return <div>
                 <iframe
                  ref={this.onIframeRef}
                  sandbox="allow-same-origin"
                  srcdoc='<html><body><textarea id="some-textarea"></textarea></body></html>'
                  ></iframe>
             </div> 
    }
```

I'm confused as to if setting `srcdoc` means the code is same origin or not since the code isn't working and `this.Iframe` has neither `contentDocument` nor `contentWindow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

srcdoc means that its the same origin, however your code is not working for the following two reasons:

1. Its true that when the componentDidMount runs that means that the iframe has been inserted in the dom, but that does not mean that it iframe itself has been loaded, and so when the the following code executes it will return null

```
iframeDoc.contentWindow.document.getElementById("some-textarea")
```

2. ```
   let textArea = iframeDoc.contentWindow.document.getElementById("some-textarea")[0]
   ```

The get element by id returns the element itself, and so the [0] will return undefined.

To make your code work you should listen for the load event on the iframe, and then run your code in that event listener (to ensure that the iframe dom itself has been loaded)

here is a running codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-turing-25wn9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, explained a lot! (The second one is what happens when you copy code)